# How can I add an amount random error to a numerical variable in R?

Tags: r, random

I am working on investigating the relationship between body measurements and overall weight in a set of biological specimens using regression equations. I have been comparing my results to previous studies, which did not draw their measurement data and body weights from the same series of individuals. Instead, these studies used the mean values reported for each species from the previously published literature (with body measurements and weight drawn from different sets of individuals) or just took the midpoint of reported ranges of body measurements.

I am trying to figure out how to introduce a small amount of random error in my data to simulate the effects of drawing measurement and weight data from different sources. For example, mutating all data to be slightly altered from their actual value by roughly +/- 5% of their actual value, which is close to the difference I get between my measurements and the literature measurements, and seeing how much that affects accuracy statistics. I know there is the `jitter()` command, but that only seems to work with plotting data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `jitter` function in base R which allows you to add random noise in the data.

```
x <- 1:10
set.seed(123)
jitter(x)
#[1] 0.915 2.115 2.964 4.153 5.176 5.818 7.011 8.157 9.021 9.983
```

Check `?jitter` which explains different ways to control the noise added.

Answer (score 0):

Straight forward if you know what the error looks like (i.e. how is your error distributed?). Is the error normally distributed? Uniform?

```
v1 <- rep(100, 10) # measurements with no noise
v1_n <- v1 + rnorm(10, 0, 20) #error with mean 0 and sd 20 sampled from normal distribution
v1_u <- v1 + runif(10, -5, 5) #error with mean 0 min -5 and max 5 from uniform distribution  

v1_n
[1]  87.47092 103.67287  83.28743 131.90562 106.59016  83.59063 109.74858 114.76649 111.51563  93.89223
v1_u
[1] 104.34705  97.12143 101.51674  96.25555  97.67221  98.86114  95.13390  98.82388 103.69691  98.40349
```